# How do I detect when a captcha is completed? Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

Currently, I am struggling with correctly identifying when a captcha has been completed. My initial strategy was to wait until the checkmark was displayed within the screen and then break the loop. What currently happens as the element.is_displayed() is returning true even though the checkmark is not showing. What is a good method to detect when a captcha has been finished manually?

```
print("Waiting for captcha completion.")
    iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/iframe"))

    )
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/span/div[4]"))

    )
    for i in range(1000):
        if element.is_displayed():
            driver.switch_to.default_content()
            button = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/button"))

            )
            break
        time.sleep(.25)
```

Comment: For recaptcha v2 you might want to try changing the callback

Answer (score 0):

This is worst practice in selenium,

CAPTCHA, short for Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart, is explicitly designed to prevent automation, so do not try! There are two primary strategies to get around CAPTCHA checks:

Disable CAPTCHAs in your test environment
Add a hook to allow tests to bypass the CAPTCHA

Comment: Hi, the software i am creating is not for a site I own. Additionally, it is not yet fully automated therefore I do manually solve the tests. That being said I just want the program to wait until I manually solve it, then proceed. Thanks for your response!